# I always have to rebuild my project before running it

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My project won't compile itself (says all files are up to date) even if I change my code.
My only solution is to rebuild every single time.

Does it have something to do with the fact that my project files are stored on a network drive at my work?

Comment: Just paranoia: Check timestamps too: local macine "now" versus remote file's "modified."

Comment: "Does it have something to do with the fact that my project files are stored on a network drive at my work?"  Well, then try to store them locally, and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying project files on your local machine and see if it works as required; also double check preferences -> Build, Execution and Deployment -> Compiler -> Make project automatically: if I recall correctly it is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Run/Debug Configuration** by combo box of in tools bar.
Then click on your project name and in bottom of **Configuration** tab exist a text area with **Before lunch: Make, Activate tool window**. click on **+** button and select **Make** option. 
This means is before any lunch your project , **intellij** compile aging your all classes and make resources.